# Node.js Server: Image Upload / Corruption Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

So I'm trying to write a basic file server in Node.js, and all the images I've tried uploading and storing on it are coming back as corrupted. The problem seems to have something to do with the way that Node Buffers handle being converted to UTF-8 and back again (which I have to do in order to get the POST body headers out and away from the binary data).

Here's a simple Node server that shows my current approach and the problems I've been having:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if (request.method === "GET") {
        // on GET request, output a simple web page with a file upload form
        var mypage = '<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">' + 
                        '<title>Submit POST Form</title></head>\r\n<body>' +
                        '<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8008" method="POST" ' + 
                        'enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input name="upload" ' + 
                        'type="file"><p><button type="submit">Submit</button>' + 
                        '</p></form></body></html>\r\n';
        response.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html",
            "Content-Length": mypage.length
        });
        response.end(mypage);

    } else if (request.method === "POST") {
        // if we have a return post request, let's capture it
        var upload = new Buffer([]);

        // get the data
        request.on('data', function(chunk) {
            // copy post data 
            upload = Buffer.concat([upload, chunk]);
        });

        // when we have all the data
        request.on('end', function() {
            // convert to UTF8 so we can pull out the post headers
            var str = upload.toString('utf8');
            // get post headers with a regular expression
            var re = /(\S+)\r\nContent-Disposition:\s*form-data;\s*name="\w+";\s*filename="[^"]*"\r\nContent-Type: (\S+)\r\n\r\n/i,
                reMatch = str.match(re);
            var lengthOfHeaders = reMatch[0].length,
                boundary = reMatch[1],
                mimeType = reMatch[2];
            // slice headers off top of post body
            str = str.slice(lengthOfHeaders);
            // remove the end boundary
            str = str.replace("\r\n" + boundary + "--\r\n", '');
            // convert back to buffer
            var rawdata = new Buffer(str, 'utf8');
            // echo back to client
            response.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Type": mimeType
            });
            response.end(rawdata);
        });
    }
});

server.listen(8008);
console.log("server running on port 8008");
```

To test it, run the script in node and go to 127.0.0.1:8008 in your browser. Try uploading an image and submitting the form. The image comes back as corrupt every time -- even though the script should just be directly echoing the image data back to the browser.

So does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a better way to handle POST body headers in Node that I haven't figured out yet? (And before anyone says anything, no, I *don't* want to use Express. I want to figure out and understand this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem seems to have something to do with the way that Node Buffers handle being converted to UTF-8 and back again

I guess you are right about that, convert to UTF-8 is a bad idea, but can do it just to work with the file and get the headers and boundaries positions, but keep the buffer file untouched, and when you have all the positions to get the header and boundary out of the file just copy the buffer to a new buffer like that

originalBuffer.copy(newBuffer,0, positionHeader, positionEndBoundary)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var connections = 0;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
connections++;
console.log(req.url,"connections: "+connections);
if(req.url == '/'){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(
        '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">' +
        '</form>'
    );
}

var body = new Buffer([]);
if (req.url == '/upload') {
    req.on('data', function (foo) {

        //f.write(foo);
        body = Buffer.concat([body,foo]);
        if(isImage(body.toString())){
            console.log("é imagem do tipo "+isImage(body.toString()));
        }
        else{
            console.log("Não é imagem");
            res.end("Não é imagem");
        }
        console.log(body.length, body.toString().length);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        // console.log(req.headers);
        //I converted the buffer to "utf 8" but i kept the original buffer
        var str = body.toString();
        console.log(str.length);
        imageType = isImage(body.toString());
        //get the index of the last header character
        //I'm just using the string to find the postions to cut the headers and boundaries
        var index = str.indexOf(imageType)+(imageType+"\r\n\r\n").length;
        // var headers= str.slice(0,index).split(';');
        // console.log(headers);

        //Here comes the trick
        /*
        *I have to cut the last boundaries, so i use the lastIndexOf to cut the second boundary
        * And maybe that is the corruption issues, because, I'm not sure, but I guess
        * the UTF-8 format only use 7bits to represent all characters, and the buffer can use 8bits, or two hex,
        *So, i need to take the difference here (body.length-str.length)  
        */ 
        var indexBoundayToBuffer = str.lastIndexOf('------WebKitFormBoundary')+(body.length-str.length);
        console.log(index, indexBoundayToBuffer);
        //maybe you can change this to use less memory, whatever
        var newBuffer = Buffer.alloc(body.length);
        /*
        *And now use the index, and the indexBoudayToBuffer and you will have only the binary
        */
        body.copy(newBuffer,0,index,indexBoundayToBuffer);

        // f.end();
        //file type
        var type = imageType.substr("image/".length);
        console.log("END");
        fs.writeFile("nameFile."+type,newBuffer,function(err,ok){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            }
            res.end();

        });
    });
}

});

function isImage(str){

if(str.indexOf('image/png')!=-1) return 'image/png';
else if(str.indexOf('image/jpeg')!=-1) return 'image/jpeg';
else if(str.indexOf('image/bmp'!=-1)) return 'image/bmp';
else if(str.indexOf('image/gif'!=-1)) return 'image/gif';
else false;
}

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(port, function () {
console.log('Recording connections on port %s', port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You *really* shouldn't use regular expressions like that to parse multipart payloads as it can easily make trying to parse your image data very unreliable. There are modules on npm that parse forms for you such as [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), or [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). None of them use regular expressions and they don't require Express.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. Seems that Busboy might work for my needs in this case. That said, I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong here. Is there anything other than the use of a regular expression that you think might be causing it?

Comment: Also, just registered [an issue](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/issues/62) on busboy. Doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You're not feeding busboy any data. Add `request.pipe(busboy);` after your event handlers.

Comment: Came back to this thread after a while. From what I can remember, that was indeed the problem. D'oh. So, yeah, if anyone's reading this in the future, busboy works fine.